# Saul and Persecution

Tags: acts, paul, apostles, persecution

Acts 8:1-3 NIV

> <sup>**1**</sup> On that day a great persecution broke out against the church in Jerusalem, and all except the apostles were scattered throughout Judea and Samaria. <sup>**2**</sup> Godly men buried Stephen and mourned deeply for him. <sup>**3**</sup> But Saul began to destroy the church. Going from house to house, he dragged off both men and women and put them in prison.

Stephen (a deacon) was just stoned to death.  So I am curious as to why Saul (later Paul) left the Apostles alone?  He went from 'house to house' and yet nothing is written to indicate Saul going after the leaders of the church.  Why?

Comment: Edited just to indicate to you how you may, if you wish, highlight quoted text. Please feel free to roll back to the original if you desire to do so.

Answer (score 1):

By the time Saul/Paul is described as ravaging the church (v. 3), "all except the apostles were scattered" (vs. 1). We are not told how much time elapsed between the beginning of the persecution and Paul's role as a leading persecutor.

Unlike Stephen, who "did great wonders and signs among the people" those who now remained in Jerusalem were surely in hiding by the time that Paul began searching for them. Moreover, as other answers have mentioned, there was a difference of policy between the high priest (a Sadducee) and Gamaliel, Paul's former teacher. Gamaliel was the leader of the [liberal faction of the Pharisees](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6494-gamaliel-i) and the president of the Sanhedrin. Paul's attitude on this matter was diametrically opposite to Gamaliel, who famously urged a policy of non-punishment of the apostles lest "we be found to be fighting against God." (Acts 5:39)

It is logical, therefore, to presume that Paul's intelligence was coming from the high priest's faction. But this group was elitist and pro-Roman, not in touch with the common people. Unlike the Pharisees, they focused on the Temple rather than the synagogues, which were the natural witnessing ground of the follows of "the Way." If Paul could not rely on intelligence from his former teacher and other leaders of the Pharisees, he would not know where the apostles were located, especially since the text indicates active steps we taken to hide from the persecution. By the term "house to house," one need not think of his going to every home in Jerusalem. Rather, he would seek information about possible house-church gatherings in a certain area and conduct a search there. The apostles, who we in hiding, could thus could escape capture relatively easily.

Beyond this is the issue raised by @Vincent Wong, namely whether Paul had the legal authority to act as described.

**Conclusion: Paul was unable to apprehend the apostles because his intelligence on the organization of the fledgling Christian church was poor. Many of his targets had scattered and others were in hiding. He probably received little help from the Pharisees (whose primary leader at the time was the tolerant Gamaliel) and the high priest did not have good sources of information at the grass roots level.**

Comment: +1. I agree - this is the simplest explanation.  Paul probably did not know much about the church and its structure & leadership which was not well developed at that stage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Op asked;

> Stephen, (a deacon) was just stoned to death. So I am curious as to why Saul, (later Paul) left the Apostles alone? He went from 'house to house' and yet nothing is written to indicate Saul going after the leaders of the church. Why?

It may be because the Apostles had already been in jail, released and told not to speak about Jesus.

> Then the captain, having gone with the officers, was bringing them, not with force, for they were afraid of the people lest they might be stoned. And having brought them, they set them in the Council. And the high priest asked them, saying "By a charge we commanded you not to teach in this name, and behold, you have filled Jerusalem with your teaching, and you intend to bring upon us the blood of this man.” Acts 5:26-28

The establishment was afraid of the people and let them alone.  A Pharisee told the council to leave Peter, John, and others to leave them alone.
So, after beating them, they did leave them alone.

> But a certain man having risen up in the Council, a Pharisee named Gamaliel, a teacher of the law honored by all the people, commanded them to put the men outside for a short while.
> "And now I say to you, withdraw from these men and let them alone, for if this plan or this work is from men, it will be overthrown. But if it is from God, you will not be able to overthrow it, lest ever also you would be found fighting against God.”
> And they were persuaded by him. And having called in the apostles, having beaten them, they commanded them not to speak in the name of Jesus, and they released them.  Acts 5:38-40

Answer (score 0):

F.F. Bruce suggests the persecution was primarily against the Hellenists:

> If we read the present paragraph in its wider context, we may conclude that it was the Hellenists in the church (the group in which Stephen had been a leader) who formed the main target of attack, and that it was they for the most part were compelled to leave Jerusalem. From this time onward the Jerusalem church appears to have consisted almost entirely of "Hebrews."<sup>`1`</sup>

This seems to follow a later description of the scattering and persecution:

> <sup>19</sup> Now those who were scattered because of the persecution that arose over Stephen traveled as far as Phoenicia and Cyprus and Antioch, speaking the word to no one except Jews. <sup>20</sup> But there were some of them, men of Cyprus and Cyrene, who on coming to Antioch spoke to the Hellenists also, preaching the Lord Jesus. <sup>21</sup> And the hand of the Lord was with them, and a great number who believed turned to the Lord. <sup>22</sup> The report of this came to the ears of the church in Jerusalem, and they sent Barnabas to Antioch. (Acts 11 ESV)

Treating those who spoke Greek and those who spoke Hebrew differently is also something which took place within the church:

> <sup>1</sup> Now in these days when the disciples were increasing in number, a complaint by the Hellenists arose against the Hebrews because their widows were being neglected in the daily distribution. <sup>2</sup> And the twelve summoned the full number of the disciples and said, “It is not right that we should give up preaching the word of God to serve tables. <sup>3</sup> Therefore, brothers, pick out from among you seven men of good repute, full of the Spirit and of wisdom, whom we will appoint to this duty. <sup>4</sup> But we will devote ourselves to prayer and to the ministry of the word.” <sup>5</sup> And what they said pleased the whole gathering, and they chose Stephen, a man full of faith and of the Holy Spirit, and Philip, and Prochorus, and Nicanor, and Timon, and Parmenas, and Nicolaus, a proselyte of Antioch. (Acts 6)

As Bruce notes, *it is remarkable that all seven have Greek names, which may suggest they all belonged to the Hellenistic group*.<sup>`2`</sup>

Therefore, just as we find deference given to the Hebrew speaking widows over the Hellenists, Saul gave deference to the Hebrew speaking believers.

---

<sub>1. F.F. Bruce, *Commentary on the Book of Acts*, Wm. B. Eerdmans Publishing Co., 1974, p. 174</sub>
<sub>2. Ibid., p. 129</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that Paul left the Apostles alone because his authority was limited. According to an earlier account in Acts 5:27-42, the Sanhedrin did not come to a consensus on how to deal with the Apostles. However, an honorable Pharisee named Gamaliel persuaded the Sanhedrin to leave the Apostles alone, he said;

> 38 Therefore, in the present case I advise you: Leave these men alone! Let them go! For if their purpose or activity is of human origin, it will fail. 39 But if it is from God, you will not be able to stop these men; you will only find yourselves fighting against God.” (Acts 5:38-39 NIV)

It should also note that before the Sanhedrin trial, the captain went with his officers and brought the apostles. They did not use force because they feared that the people would stone them (Acts 5:26).

Although Paul was a student of Gamaliel (Acts 22:3), he sided with the high priest who gave him the letter to arrest Christians in Damascus (Acts 9:1-2). It was likely Gamaliel's speech only suppressed the intention to target the Apostles. The high priest knew that if they raised a riot in town by targeting the Apostles, it would bring the attention of the Romans authorities.